# ' Range.Find' and ' Range.FindNext' to loop only over the first match

Tags: excel, vba, loops, scope, find

I am looping through a set of data with VBA Excel.  I am trying to find a certain string using a combination the `Range.Find` and the `Range.FindNext` methods.  I having a hard time figuring out where to place these statements because I need them to be in the scope of each other but at the same time I don't want the first `Find` statement to keep executing every time, hence only looping over the first match.

```
Sub AssignGroups()

    Dim membership As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim groups As Worksheet
    Dim nameRow As Long
    Dim fullNameString As String
    Dim nameRange As Range
    Dim groupRange As Range
    Dim nameRange2 As Range
    Dim nameIndex As Long
    Dim userNameString As String
    Dim barIndex As Long



    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set membership = Sheets("User Group Membership")
    Set groups = Sheets("User Assigned to Groups")
    Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").Find("user -name", Lookat:=xlPart)


    If Not nameRange Is Nothing Then

        firstAddress = nameRange.Address
        Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").Find("user -name", Lookat:=xlPart)
    Do

    membership.Activate
    nameRow = nameRange.Row
    MsgBox (nameRow)
    fullNameString = membership.Cells(nameRow, "A").Value
    MsgBox (fullNameString)
    nameIndex = InStr(fullNameString, "user -name")
    barIndex = InStr(fullNameString, "|")
    MsgBox (nameIndex)
    MsgBox (barIndex)
    userNameString = Mid(fullNameString, nameIndex + 12, ((barIndex - 4) - (nameIndex + 12)))

    groups.Activate
    Set nameRange2 = groups.Range("A:CH").Find(userNameString)
    nameColumn = nameRange2.Column



    membership.Activate
    membership.Cells(nameRow, "A").Activate

    Do
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Activate

        If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

            cellValue = ActiveCell.Value
            groups.Activate
            Set groupRange = groups.Range("A:CH").Find(cellValue, , , Lookat:=xlWhole)
            groupRow = groupRange.Row
            groups.Cells(groupRow, nameColumn).Activate
            ActiveCell.Value = "X"
            membership.Activate

         End If



        Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

    Set nameRange = membership.Range("A:A").FindNext(ActiveCell)

    Loop While Not nameRange Is Nothing And nameRange.Address <> firstAddress
    End If


End Sub
```

How could I place these statements so that it would loop over all the matches, one after another?